# nodejs socket receive data from one port and make available on another port

Tags: node.js, socket.io, port

I have two devices. One devices send data to one socket port ie. 9000 and another devices connected to another port ie. 8000 and I want 2nd device receive same data that is received on port 9000 from first device.

I want to make a script using nodejs and socket io to receive data from one port like: `192.168.25.42:9000` and same received data should be available on different port `192.168.25.42:8000`

any help appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use the same port? Can you give a little context please. So we can better understand your needs.

Comment: I want, when 9000 port receive any data, this data should be immediate available on port 8000. Devices are already built and we can't change their logic. Can't use same port.

Comment: So just to be clear: socket.io server on port 9000 receives data from client, you want to push that data to clients connected to port 8000?

Comment: yes, exactly. any idea how can do ?

Comment: I see you rarely accept an answer, people take time to help you, yet you don't have the decency to comment when is helping you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have 2 socket.io servers, one listening on port 9000 and the other one listening on port 8000.

When one server receives data, you emit that data to the other one.

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require('http');

const app8000 = express();
const app9000 = express();

const server8000 = http.Server(app8000);
const server9000 = http.Server(app9000);

const io8000 = require('socket.io')(server8000);
const io9000 = require('socket.io')(server9000);

server8000.listen(8000);
server9000.listen(9000);

// Server on port 8000

io8000.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('my-event', data => {
        //Push data to clients connected to server on port 9000
        io9000.emit("event-from-8000", "From 8000: " + data);
    });
});

// Server on port 9000

io9000.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('my-event', data => {
        //Push data to clients connected to server on port 8000
        io8000.emit("event-from-9000", "From 9000: " + data);
    });
});
```