# Node.js Emit Packet across Ports

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have a server.js and client.js pair of script files.

Here is the server.js file...

```
var express = require('express');
var appMain = express(); var appReset = express();
var serverMain = require('http').Server(appMain);
var serverReset = require('http').Server(appReset);
var fs = require('fs');

appMain.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});
appMain.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

appReset.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/reset.html');
});
appReset.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serverMain.listen(3000); console.log('Start mainServer');
serverReset.listen(2000); console.log('Start resetServer');

var gameScores;

fs.readFile('client/data/scores.txt', 'utf8', function(error, data) {
    if (error) {
        console.log('Read Error!');
        gameScores = null;
    }
    else {
        console.log('Read Success!');
        gameScores = data;
    }
});

var ioMain = require('socket.io') (serverMain,{});
ioMain.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('mainSocket Connected');
    socket.emit('gameScores', gameScores);
    socket.on('gameScores', function(data) {
        gameScores = data;
        fs.writeFile('client/data/scores.txt', JSON.stringify(data), function(error) {
            if (error)
                console.log('Write Error!');
            else
                console.log('Write Success!');
        });
        socket.emit('gameScores', gameScores);
    });
});

var ioReset = require('socket.io') (serverReset,{});
ioReset.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('resetSocket Connected');
    socket.on('resetScores', function(data) {
        fs.unlink('client/data/scores.txt', function(error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Delete Error!');
                socket.emit('clearScores', false);
            }
            else {
                console.log('Delete Success!');
                gameScores = null;
                socket.emit('defaultScores', gameScores);
                socket.emit('clearScores', true);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the client.js file...

```
socket.on('gameScores', function(data) {
    if (data !== null) {
        if (JSON.parse(localStorage.reload))
            localStorage.reload = false;
        else
            localStorage.gameScores = JSON.stringify(data);
        localStorage.emptyScores = false;
    }
    else {
        localStorage.emptyScores = true;
        localStorage.reload = false;
    }
});
socket.on('defaultScores', function(data) {
    if (data == null) {
        console.log('Received Default from Server');
        localStorage.emptyScores = true;
        Game.main.gameScores('load');
    }
});
```

All the code of these two files is working correctly, except in the server.js file where you see the comment "Delete Success!" that is followed by three lines of code. Of these three lines, the specific line which is not working is the following:

```
socket.emit('defaultScores', gameScores);
```

The above line of code should transmit a data packet to the corresponding socket receiver in the client.js file of label "defaultScores" but the client never receives it. I know the client does not receive it because the comment "Received Default from Server" does not print to client console. Once the socket receiver in question is able to successfully work, thus printing the comment in question, the rest should work fine.

Thus, I am specifically requesting for assistance in getting the comment "Received Default from Server" to print to client console successfully.

Comment: have you tried logging `data` before the null check in the `defaultScore` client function?

Comment: @Joe Thank you, but you'll have to clarify what you mean. I don't understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: Sorry, I meant try to log the `data` argument from within this function: `socket.on('defaultScores', function(data) {...});`

Comment: @Joe Understood. I had assumed it was a sure bet that even if I moved the comment "Received Default from Server" just above the IF statement that it's contained within, that still the comment wouldn't appear. Nonetheless, I have now tried moving the comment in question to just before the IF statement, and as expect, still the comment doesn't appear. The problem I suspect is that somehow in the server.js file, for the second line of code that appears after the comment "Delete Success!", I need to be able to say emit over port 3000 and not port 2000....

Comment: @Joe As I typed that last comment, the thought occurred to me to test and confirm if over port 2000 it would work and be received. Sure enough, it did. So that definitely tells me that the specific fix needed is to somehow instead specify to emit over port 3000 and not port 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out on my own. Thankfully I came across the following previous post...

[nodejs socket receive data from one port and make available on another port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44225028/nodejs-socket-receive-data-from-one-port-and-make-available-on-another-port)

From the article, I was able to infer that the change I needed, from the second line of code after the "Delete Success!" comment, was to change to this...

```
ioMain.emit('defaultScores', gameScores);
```

This successfully resolved the problem.